# python: extracting a .bz2 compressed file from a torrent file

Tags: python, bittorrent, bz2

I have a .torrent file that contains a .bz2 file. I am sure that such a file is actually in the .torrent because I extracted the .bz2 with utorrent.

How can I do the same thing in python instead of using utorrent?

I have seen a lot of libraries for dealing with .torrent files in python but apparently none does what I need. Among my unsuccessful attempts I can mention:

```
import torrent_parser as tp
file_cont = tp.parse_torrent_file('RC_2015-01.bz2.torrent')
```

`file_cont` is now a dictionary and `file_cont['info']['name']='RC_2015-01.bz2'` but if I try to open the file, i.e.

```
from bz2 import BZ2File
with BZ2File(file_cont['info']['name']) as f:
    what_I_want = f.read()
```

then the content of the dictionary is (obviously, I'd say) interpreted as a path, and I get

```
No such file or directory: 'RC_2015-01.bz2'
```

Other attempts have been even more ruinous.

Comment: You realize `.torrent` files don't contain the file itself, right? You need to download (via the BitTorrent protocol) the file before a file with such a name exists.

Comment: And python doesn't allow to do so?

Comment: You could use (or write) a library to actually perform the download, but Python doesn't magically do it for you. It's magic, but not *that* magic.

Comment: Yeah, I strongly relies on python being magic and on other people (WAY better than me with python) writing libraries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `.torrent` file is just a [metadata file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torrent_file), indicating where to get the data and the filename of the file. You can't get the file contents from that file.

Only once you have successfully downloaded this torrent file to disk (using torrent software) you can then use BZ2File to open it (if it is `.bz2` format).

If you want to perform the actual download with Python, the only option I found was [torrent-dl](https://github.com/animeshkundu/torrent-dl) which hasn't been updated for 2 years.